# How to receive what was sent by convertAndSend?

Tags: java, spring, jms

I'm reading [Spring Framework reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jms.html), chapter about JMS integration. There are some examples for sending text messages and asynchronously receiving them (by listeners). And there is also an example for `JmsTemplate` function `convertAndSend` which converts given object to a message. The reference says:

> By using the converter, you and your application code can focus on the business object that is being sent or received via JMS and not be concerned with the details of how it is represented as a JMS message.

But there is no example for receiving such messages. They mention function `receiveAndConvert` but, unfortunately, it receives synchronously.
So how am I to receive it asynchronously? Must I be aware that when I `convertAndSend` a `Map`, the resulting message will be a `MapMessage`, and just check in my listener for this type of message and handle it? But they promised I'm not to be concerned  with the details of how it is represented as a JMS message.
So is there a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While `JmsTemplate` provides basic synchronous receive methods, asynchronous reception is a whole lot more complicated, and is beyond the scope of `JmsTemplate`.

Asynchronous reception of JMS messages is done in Spring using [Message Listener Containers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-mdp), which asynchronously take messages from the JMS destination and pass them to your application. You can plug a `MessageConverter` in to your message listener container via a [MessageListenerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-receiving-async-message-listener-adapter) (plug the converter into the adapter, plug your application's listener into the adapter, then plug the adapter into the listener container).

Answer (score 13):

I know it's been a while since this was asked, but I had the same problem, solved it and wanted to give an explicit code example here.

Here's my `MessageListener`. This implements the `onMessage(Message)` method to intercept messages asynchronously.

```
package com.package.amqp;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageListener;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter;

import com.package.model.User;

public class TestListener implements MessageListener {

        public void onMessage(Message message) {
            JsonMessageConverter jmc = new JsonMessageConverter();
            User u = (User)jmc.fromMessage(message);
            System.out.println("received: " + u.getFirstName());
        }
}
```

The messages are then converted using the standard `JsonMessageConvertor` in my case as this is the `messageConvertor` I plugged into my `rabbitTemplate` bean.

```
<bean id="rabbitConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="10.10.1.2"/>
    <property name="username" value="guest"/>
    <property name="password" value="guest"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="rabbitConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="queueName" value="queue.helloWorld"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="someListener"/>
</bean>

<bean id="someListener" class="com.package.amqp.TestListener"></bean>

<bean id="rabbitTemplate" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="rabbitConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="messageConverter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Hope this helps someone!
Owen

Comment: How to receive messages with a service-activator instea of MessageListener?

Comment: @luksmir, I'm not familiar with Spring Integration, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351948/using-spring-integration-with-rabbitmq may help you?