# spring batch remote chunking doesn't queue messages but runs it locally?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-batch-admin

Below is my configuration for spring batch remote chunking. My steps are running locally instead of remotely. I cant see messages in rabbitmq.

```
<beans:bean id="importExchangesChunkItemWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter"
    scope="step" p:messagingOperations-ref="importExchangesMessagingTemplate"
    p:replyChannel-ref="importExchangesReplyChannel">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="importExchangesChunkHandler"
    class="org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.RemoteChunkHandlerFactoryBean"
    p:chunkWriter-ref="importExchangesChunkItemWriter" p:step-ref="importExchangesStep">
</beans:bean>

<job id="importExchangesJob" restartable="true">    
     <step id="importExchangesStep" next="importEclsStep">
        <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <chunk reader="importExchangesFileItemReader" writer="importExchangesItemWriter"
                commit-interval="${import.exchanges.commit.interval}" />
        </tasklet>
    </step>    
  </job>



<beans:bean id="passThroughItemProcessor" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.PassThroughItemProcessor" />

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
    port="${rabbitmq.port}" host="${rabbitmq.host}" username="${rabbitmq.username}"
    password="${rabbitmq.password}" />

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:admin id="rmqAdmin" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:queue name="${import.exchanges.queue}" />
<rabbit:queue name="${import.exchanges.reply.queue}" />

<int:channel id="importExchangesChannel" />


<int:channel id="importExchangesReplyChannel" />


<beans:bean id="importExchangesMessagingTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate"
    p:defaultChannel-ref="importExchangesChannel" p:receiveTimeout="${import.exchanges.reply.timeout}" />

<amqp:outbound-channel-adapter id="importExchangesOutboundAdapter"
    channel="importExchangesChannel" />

<amqp:inbound-channel-adapter id="importExchangesInboundAdapter"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory" channel="importExchangesReplyChannel"
    queue-names="${import.exchanges.reply.queue}" />


<amqp:inbound-channel-adapter id="importExchangesSlaveInboundAdapter"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory" channel="importExchangesChannel"
    queue-names="${import.exchanges.queue}" />



<amqp:outbound-channel-adapter id="importExchangesSlaveOutboundAdapter"
    channel="importExchangesReplyChannel" />

<int:service-activator id="serviceActivatorExchanges"
    input-channel="importExchangesChannel" output-channel="importExchangesReplyChannel"
    ref="chunkProcessorChunkHandlerExchanges" method="handleChunk" />


<beans:bean id="importExchangesItemWriter"
    class="com.st.batch.foundation.ImportExchangesItemWriter" p:symfony-ref="symfony" p:replyTimeout="${import.exchanges.reply.timeout}"/>



<beans:bean id="chunkProcessorExchanges"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor"
    p:itemWriter-ref="importExchangesItemWriter" p:itemProcessor-ref="passThroughItemProcessor"/>

<beans:bean id="chunkProcessorChunkHandlerExchanges"
    class="org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkProcessorChunkHandler"
    p:chunkProcessor-ref="chunkProcessorExchanges" />
```

Changed configuration to this, now it queue single message at a time and doesn't process multiple (should process number of messages equal to listener concurrency).

```
<beans:bean id="simpleThreadScope"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.SimpleThreadScope" />

<util:map id="scopesMap">
    <beans:entry key="thread" value-ref="simpleThreadScope" />
</util:map>

<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer"
    p:scopes-ref="scopesMap" />





<int:channel id="importExchangesChannel" />
<int:channel id="importExchangesReplyChannel" scope="thread">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<beans:bean id="importExchangesMessagingTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate"
    p:defaultChannel-ref="importExchangesChannel" p:receiveTimeout="${import.exchanges.reply.timeout}" />

<amqp:outbound-channel-adapter
    amqp-template="amqpTemplate" channel="importExchangesChannel"
    exchange-name="${import.exchanges.exchange}" routing-key="${import.exchanges.routing.key}" />

<rabbit:listener-container
    connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" concurrency="${import.exchanges.listener.concurrency}"
    requeue-rejected="false" prefetch="1">
    <rabbit:listener queues="${import.exchanges.queue}"
        ref="importExchangesChunkHandler" method="handleChunk" />
</rabbit:listener-container>


<int:channel id="importEclsChannel" />
<int:channel id="importEclsReplyChannel" scope="thread">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<beans:bean id="importEclsMessagingTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate"
    p:defaultChannel-ref="importEclsChannel" p:receiveTimeout="${import.ecls.reply.timeout}" />

<amqp:outbound-channel-adapter
    amqp-template="amqpTemplate" channel="importEclsChannel"
    exchange-name="${import.ecls.exchange}" routing-key="${import.ecls.routing.key}" />

<rabbit:listener-container
    connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" concurrency="${import.ecls.listener.concurrency}"
    requeue-rejected="false" prefetch="1">
    <rabbit:listener queues="${import.ecls.queue}"
        ref="importEclsChunkHandler" method="handleChunk" />
</rabbit:listener-container>



<beans:bean id="importExchangesItemWriter"
    class="com.st.batch.foundation.ImportExchangesItemWriter"
    p:symfony-ref="symfony" p:replyTimeout="${import.exchanges.reply.timeout}" />


<beans:bean id="importExchangesChunkItemWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter"
    scope="step" p:messagingOperations-ref="importExchangesMessagingTemplate"
    p:replyChannel-ref="importExchangesReplyChannel">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="importExchangesChunkHandler"
    class="org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.RemoteChunkHandlerFactoryBean"
    p:chunkWriter-ref="importExchangesChunkItemWriter" p:step-ref="importExchangesStep">
</beans:bean>

<rabbit:queue name="${import.exchanges.queue}" />
<rabbit:queue name="${import.exchanges.reply.queue}" />

<rabbit:direct-exchange name="${import.exchanges.exchange}">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="${import.exchanges.queue}"
            key="${import.exchanges.routing.key}" />
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:direct-exchange>
```

I can see only 1 message in queue at a time. I should sent messages = ${import.exchanges.commit.interval} and all should be picked up by concurrent listeners and processed parallely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "running locally" but you don't have any routing information on the outbound adapters; if rabbit doesn't know how to route messages, he simply drops them.

You need to add `routing-key="${import.exchanges.queue}"` and `routing-key="${import.exchanges.reply.queue}"` to the adapters. This will use the default exchange ("") where the queues are bound using their names.

Also, you can't use the same channel name on both sides (`importExchangesChannel`). That way, the outbound adapter and service activator will both be subscribed and messages will be distributed in round-robin fashion.

So, some chunks will run locally; others will be dropped because of the routing key problem.

You need to fix the routing key and use a different channel on service side.

Comment: Thanks Gary, "runnnig locally" I mean, ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter is not writing to queue so messages (commands) running on only 1 server and not distributed on other servers. It is working like remote chunking has no effect on batch steps, step writers are directly executed locally instead of remotely